# Why is the texturing on my model rendering blurry and without the alpha chanel?

Tags: materials, transparency, blur

I'm trying to make a render of a minecraft charterer. This would be simple enough, but I am a total noob with blender. I texture mapped it just fine, but it comes out blurry and the alpha chanel (that shows up perfectly while editing) is pure white. I need it to look like does in editer when I render it. I am at a total loss, I don't know how to fix this. I really need some help[image]

picture on the right is the texture, the picture on the middle is how it looks in the editer, and the picture in the middle is how it looks when rendered.

Comment: As for the transparency, make sure *alpha* is checked in *Properties > Texture panel > Influence*.

Comment: I fixed the blurring issue, but when I checked that box, it simply changed the white to black. Perhaps there is a conflict between settings. either way, I don't know what to do. I need more help